# Perl SSH into Device

Tags: perl, ssh, cisco-ios

I am having a strange problem and I want to get to the bottom of this:

I have a list of more than 1000 CISCO devices that I need to ssh into and run some commands. So in Perl, I have the following code:

```
my $scon = Net::SSH::Perl->new("192.168.110.45");
$scon->login($username,$password);
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit)= $scon->cmd('show run');
print "\n$stdout\n";
```

And the above code works showing me the output that I need.

But, when I create a loop and try to ssh each device within a loop, I get $stdout as blank.

Below is the code that doesn't work:

```
my @allhosts = `cat hosts_ip.txt | cut -d',' -f2`;
foreach my $ip (@allhosts) {
    my $scon = Net::SSH::Perl->new($ip);
    $scon->login($username,$password);
    my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit)= $scon->cmd('show run');
    print "$stdout\n";
}
```

The output from above is just blank - It returns nothing.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should try [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel)

Comment: Add `debug=>true` in your call to new?

Comment: Can you please try printing `$stderr` and `$exit`. Also can you verify array `@allhosts` and value in `$ip`

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [PSSH](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/)?  It's a Python script, but it works great for running a few commands quickly on many hosts.  It might not be exactly what you're looking for if you're stuck with Perl, but it sounds like this might be a one-time task.